# pandas - converting d-mmm-yy to datetime object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV with some data that looks like such:

[image: excel doc]

I have many of these files, and I want to read them into DataFrame:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, engine='c')
df['closingDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['closingDate'], format='%dd-%mmm-%yy')
df['Fut Expiration Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Fut Expiration Date'], format='%d-%m-%yy')
```

I've tried a multitude of formats, but none seem to work. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually you do not *need* to specify the format here. The format is *unambiguous*, if we convert it without specifying a format, we get:

```
>>> df
       Date
0  1-Dec-99
1  1-Jul-99
2  1-Jun-99
3  1-Nov-99
4  1-Oct-99
5  1-Sep-99
6  2-Aug-99
7  2-Dec-99
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
0   1999-12-01
1   1999-07-01
2   1999-06-01
3   1999-11-01
4   1999-10-01
5   1999-09-01
6   1999-08-02
7   1999-12-02
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Alternatively, we can look up the format in the documentation of the [`datetime` module <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). We here se that:

> ```
> %d   Day of the month as a zero-padded       01, 02, ., 31
>      decimal number.
>
> %b   Month as locale's abbreviated name.     Jan, Feb, ., Dec (en_US);
>                                              Jan, Feb, ., Dez (de_DE)
>
> %y   Year without century as a               00, 01, ., 99
>      zero-padded decimal number.
> ```

So we can specify the format as:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d-%b-%y')
0   1999-12-01
1   1999-07-01
2   1999-06-01
3   1999-11-01
4   1999-10-01
5   1999-09-01
6   1999-08-02
7   1999-12-02
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: What version of pandas is this for? (0.17 here) I tried to unambiguously parse this and it was an unconvertible string for me.

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois: Locally `pd.__version__== '0.22.0'`.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the insight! Very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Use `%b` for a three letter month. Please see the Python `strftime` reference: http://strftime.org/

I think you want: `w` for the day, `b` for the month, and `yy` for the year.

I'm assuming the days aren't zero padded, if the days are zero padded then use `d` instead of `w`.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the directives for [datetimes here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). The following should work, using 3 letter months and 2 digit years:

```
df['Fut Expiration Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Fut Expiration Date'], format='%d-%b-%y')
```